# How to restrict modification to event creator only?

Tags: google-calendar

I am trying to setup a shared Google Calendar where users can add and modify events *they* created but they cannot modify a different user's event. I know that the calendar app can allow one to modify all or none but I don't know how to set it in this restricted manner.

Currently I have it setup where invited users of the calendar can make changes (third option under share with specific people). I tried the second option (See all event details) but it is too limiting.